# Getting output from for-loop in r

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to write this for loop code in R, but this error occur.

```
Error in h(i - 1) : could not find function "h"
```

What should I do?

```
F1<-as.matrix(F_1_) #importing data
a01=0.1             #importing parameters
a11=0.1
b11=0.1
epsilon=0.5
a02=0.1
a12=0.1
b12=0
h(0) <- 0.3208   #starting value for h(i)

for(i in 1:2377)
{
 h(i)<- ((a01+a11*h(i-1)*(epsilon^2)*h(i-1)*b11)+F1[,2]*(a02+a12*h(i-1)*(epsilon^2)+h(i-1)*b12))
}
return(h(i))       #getting output from h(i), h(i) depend on h(i-1) and other parameters
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to make `h` a vector for results right? If you are, then () are the wrong brackets for subsetting a vector, use []. For example `letters[2]`. It's also good practice to allocate your vector first and not put your magic numbers in the for loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot. my problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `h()` assumes h is a function.

You can set h as an empty list, initialize it and iterate over it.

```
h <- list()
h[[1]] <- 0 # or whatever initial value
for(i in 2:2377)
{
 h[[i]]<- ((a01+a11*h[[i-1]]*(epsilon^2)*h[[i-1]]*b11)+F1[,2]*(a02+a12*h[[i-1]]*(epsilon^2)+h[[i-1]]*b12))
}
```

Alternatively you can initialize h as a vector of 0 and iterate the same way.